# How to run an Angular2 webpack distribution in production

Tags: angular, webpack

I have followed the steps from the [Angular2 webpack tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html), using the command:

```
npm run build
```

To compile the app into the `/dist` folder. What I am wondering now is **how can I run this distribution in production?**

I have tried doing the following:

```
cd /PATH_OF_MY_PROJECT/dist/
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:375:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:406:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:345:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:399:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:406:10)
```

Have anyone seen this error before?

**---- UPDATE ----**

Seems like updating the node version to *7.7.0* I got rid of that error, but it's not good enough, now I am getting:

```
Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at Class.run (/Users/anderustarroz/Sites/work/harris-partners/harris-face-frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:22:63)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/Users/anderustarroz/Sites/work/harris-partners/harris-face-frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:103:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Comment: Does it run normally without webpack?

Comment: When I run `npm start` it works just fine (dev version)

Comment: `npm start` will generally startup the project using Webpack. Since the error is coming from a NodeJS process, I would install a simper server and test with that to compare the results. Try `npm i -g http-server` and `cd dist` and `http-server`.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem using **http-server**:

```
npm install http-server --save
```

And adding the following configuration to the scripts section on **package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "server:production": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors -p3000"
  },
```

Then I can run the server using `npm run`:

```
npm run server:production
```